# Duvida na criaçao de tela de uma aplicacao java web

Tags: java

ola sou novo no ramo de progamacao estou acabando o curso agora gostaria de sabe se em uma aplicacao  web tem como tira aquela barra de navegador onde vc digita as url comando e demais  onde atualiza a pagina essas coisa deixa ela  igual uma desktop mesmo   obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Acredito que será mais fácil fazer isso com javascript do que com código java, dê uma olhada neste link: https://saher42.wordpress.com/2006/08/10/hiding-the-address-bar-on-pageload-using-javascript/

Comment: Você pode ver como funciona para deixar a página em full Screen (F11).
Já vi pessoas que fazem isso acontecer após o carregamento da pagina.